# Make responsive for images

Tags: css

```css
.image {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.wallpaperhub.app/cloudcache/1/b/5/8/e/f/1b58ef6e3d36a42e01992accf5c52d6eea244353.jpg');
}

.box-1,
.box-2,
.content{
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.content {
  padding: 30px;
}

.image {
  flex-basis: 70%;
}

.box-1 .image {
  clip-path: circle(farthest-side at 20% 50%);
}

.box-2 .image {
  clip-path: circle(farthest-side at 80% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-1">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, non. Molestias voluptas velit quae itaque natus nam odio obcaecati minima recusandae enim eos mollitia est animi incidunt,
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box-2">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, non. Molestias voluptas velit quae itaque natus nam odio obcaecati minima recusandae enim eos mollitia est animi incidunt, beatae iure perspiciatis.
  </div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Now the images corners are not connected, and trying to resize the width the corners also won't be connected.
How to make image corners connected?

Comment: don't repeat the same question 3 times using code you got in answers. Edit your question to add more details and wait for more answers

Comment: @Temani Afif,  could you help?